# Nginx not passing post request to subdomain properly

Tags: nginx, post, cors

I am having issues passing a post request to database on subdomain from top-level domain.

I have a django backend connecting a Postgresql database with an Angular frontend and am using gunicorn and nginx as my server setup.

I have a contact form on the website, which should be logging contacts in the database.
I have configured nginx to act as a reverse proxy, and can fetch data from the database to display on the site, but cannot seem to figure out how to get the data from the contact form to post to the database.
My nginx config:

```
    location /contact {
        set $cors_p '';
        if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://<top-level domain>\.uk|www\.<top-level domain>\.uk') {
            set $cors_p 'true';
        }

        if ($cors_p = 'true') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '$http_origin' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control_Methods' 'POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Tyoe,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 308;
        }
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    location / {
        set $cors '';
        if ($http_origin ~ '^https?://<top-level domain>\.uk|www\.<top-level domain>\.uk')      {
                set $cors 'true';
        }

        if ($cors = 'true') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
                # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
                #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;
        }

        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
        }
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
```

but in chromes dev tools I get this output:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.<top-level domain>.uk/contact' from origin 'https://<top-level domain>.uk' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

As far as I can tell, the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is being set in the '/contact' location directive.

The nginx access.log records this:

```
"OPTIONS /contact HTTP/1.1" 308 180 "https://<top-level domain>.uk/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

The top-level domain (both with and without 'www') are using https and the subdomain ('api.') are responding to GET requests correctly, but not POST requests.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?